# Disable individual menu item in ng2-bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

How can I disable the individual menu item in ng2-bootstrap dropdown menu?

I tried .disabled style from bootstrap v4 document. It seems not working in Angular2 environment.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all provide sample of your code. Then try `[disabled]="condition"`.